# Libertine's discretionary and historical ligatures with ConTeXt and XeTeX

Tags: xetex, context, ligatures, libertine, context-mkii

I would like activate Libertine's discretionary and historical ligatures with ConTeXt and XeTeX compilation.

Currently, I'm using this:

```
\definetypeface[Libertine][rm][Xserif][Linux Libertine O]
\setupbodyfont[Libertine, 9pt]

\starttext
fi ffl ct st
\stoptext
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The cheap solution: You can enable font features globally by adding them to the default feature set:

```
%% The “default” set is always active.
\definefontfeature [default] [default] [
  liga=yes,
  hlig=yes,
  dlig=yes,
]

\definetypeface[Libertine][rm][Xserif][Linux Libertine O]
\setupbodyfont[Libertine, 9pt]

\starttext
fi ffl ct st
\stoptext
```

For more precise control over when the ligatures are activated you will need a [*typescript*](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-fonts.pdf).
This lets you specify which feature sets are enabled for each type face individually. But you could as well turn ligatures off for, say, the bold face by requesting `features=default` in the relevant line. Below example applies the ligature set to all four serif faces:

```
%% 1. Create a feature set, inheriting the defaults.
\definefontfeature [extraligatures] [default] [liga=yes,script=latn,hlig=yes,dlig=yes]

%% 2. Map font files for Libertine to type faces, applying the “extraligatures” features.
\starttypescript [serif] [mylibertine]
    \definefontsynonym[Serif]           [file:LinLibertine_R]    [features=extraligatures]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifItalic]     [file:LinLibertine_RI]   [features=extraligatures]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifBold]       [file:LinLibertine_RB]   [features=extraligatures]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifBoldItalic] [file:LinLibertine_RBI]  [features=extraligatures]
\stoptypescript

% 3. Define corresponding type face identifier.
\definetypeface [mylibertine] [rm] [serif] [mylibertine] [default]

% 4. Use the font in the document.
\setupbodyfont[mylibertine]

% 5. Test all four defined styles.
\def\ligatest#1{\bgroup#1fi ffl ct st\egroup\par}
\starttext
  \processcommacommand[,\italic,\bold,\bolditalic]\ligatest
\stoptext
```

[image: Output of above snippet.]

NB: Xetex neither has good support in ConTeXt nor is it widely used. You might consider switching to MkIV which comes with greatly improved font handling facilities and is actively developed.