# Discretionary and historical ligatures with ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, ligatures, quoting

How can i use discretionary and historical ligatures with ConTeXt (MK IV) in quotations (or in certain block of text)?

Comment: Perhaps this gives you most of what you need (if so we can close as a duplicate). If not, perhaps you can edit your question showing some code. [Libertine's discretionary and historical ligatures with ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71279/2693)

Comment: @AlanMunn The linked question refers to MKII with XeTeX backend.  I would guess that OP is using MKIV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Featuresets](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Featuresets).  To use it in a quotation, just add the features in the font style.

```
\setupbodyfont[libertine]

\definefontfeature
  [hist]
  [hlig=yes]

\definefontfeature
  [rare]
  [dlig=yes]

\setupquotation
  [style={\feature[+][hist,rare]}]

\starttext

strict {\feature[+][hist]strict}

wurtzite {\feature[+][rare]wurtzite}

\quotation{strict wurtzite}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: +1 It's good to see ConTeXt questions being answered as quickly as LaTeX ones.

Comment: Works fine with Linux Libertine, now I have to find out how to use my favourite Alegreya font. :)

Comment: @ReRunner Alegreya has neither `dlig` nor `hlig` so these ligatures will not work.  But to use Alegreya with ConTeXt you can use [this typescript](https://gist.github.com/hmenke/560c97608520cd9419843f977d553d3b).